# Network Maintenance and High Availability Group Prep

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, high-availability

We have had a RAID card on one of our switches die, and the replacement had issues which caused my availability groups to failover multiple times between my 2 nodes like a game of tennis and left a few databases in an unhealthy state.

Obviously, the card needs to still be replaced again and I want to be able to set a maintenance setting to not have the databases failover repeatedly for what will be a brief blip. This will take place at a time of low activity this time, not peak activity.

Are there any best practices relating to this?
What would be the safest way to leave the databases online for most of the time (except the blip) and not have them failover multiple times?

Do I shut down the inactive node? Do I stop data movement?

We have 2 nodes running SQL 2016 Standard and 50 availability groups.

Any tips or ideas would be great.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the failover mode to "manual" then they should not failover automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would this be considered the best practice in this scenario or is there something else I should consider?

Comment: Best practise would be to change replicas to Synchronous Commit, failover to a replica that won't be affected by any outage from the change, perform your change and then failback after the change once replicas are synchronised, and finally reset any Asynchronous replicas that were changed to Synchronous.